# Dynamically turn on/off antialiasing and shadows in WebGLRenderer

Tags: three.js, antialiasing, shadow-mapping

How can I dynamically turn on and off antialiasing and shadows in WebGLRenderer?

Simply changing the properties of anti-aliasing and shadowMapEnable does not work. I looked in the source and found a method updateShadowMap () but it was removed in release 69.

UPDATE: OK, the answer to the second half of the question I found here
https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/2466

As a result the following code works fine:

```
renderer.shadowMapEnabled = false;

for(var i in tiles.children)
tiles.children[i].material.needsUpdate=true;

renderer.clearTarget( sun.shadowMap );
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't enable/diable antialiasing from a WebGL context after creation. The only way is to create a new context and submit all the buffers and textures again.

So, ideally you would only need to create a new `WebGLRenderer` with the antialias boolean. This doesn't work yet thought, but I'm working to have it working ASAP.

Comment: Hey I realize you posted this quite some time ago. Is this working now? I would love to implement dynamic rendering options based on fps. i.e. low fps = no AA, etc.

Comment: You can now create multiple `WebGLRenderer`s, yep.