# Determine base line performance before running? - ThreeJS

Tags: three.js

I want to do a Quick Test to determine if there machine can handle antialisasing and shadows, instead of after everything is running. Is there a way to do a quick performance test to see if its likely they can handle it?

Currently I have it saying on mobile don't use antialiasing, but my laptop can't handle it that well in my project.

I'd like to run a quick GPU performance test in less then 1 second to get a rough estimate of how well the GPU is going to handle and then just set the settings accordingly.

What is the suggested approach? Creating two webgl renders, and then depending on how well its performing in real time switch it over?

[Dynamically turn on/off antialiasing and shadows in WebGLRenderer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27554969/dynamically-turn-on-off-antialiasing-and-shadows-in-webglrenderer)

Edit*

Found it wasn't to painful to use two webgl renders, adjusting back and forth depending on there FPS ended up being the slightly more messy part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Two ended up not being to painful. I just had to decide when to use one over the other and hide the canvas of the inactive one. The harder part is knowing when I should be using one over the other, but currently I am checking the last 5 secounds avg FPS and if is ever less then 25 I switch to the faster renderer.

```
  renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true });
rendererTwo = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
activeRender = renderer;
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);

rendererTwo.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
rendererTwo.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);

document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
document.body.appendChild(rendererTwo.domElement);

/* Resize */
THREEx.WindowResize(renderer, camera)
THREEx.WindowResize(rendererTwo, camera)
/* Controls */
controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
controls.enableDamping = true;
controls.dampingFactor = .15;
controls.rotateSpeed = 0.25; 
controls.enableZoom = true;
controls.maxPolarAngle  = Math.PI / 2.1;
controls.minPolarAngle = 0;

/* Controls */
controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, rendererTwo.domElement);
controls.enableDamping = true;
controls.dampingFactor = .15;
controls.rotateSpeed = 0.25;
controls.enableZoom = true;
controls.maxPolarAngle = Math.PI / 2.1;
controls.minPolarAngle = 0;
```